# How to filter all quarterly time-series from a list?

Tags: r, list, time-series

I have got a list that contains several time-series with different different length and different frequencies. Something similiar to this:

```
library(tstools)

list <- list(ts(runif(200), end =  c(2021,1), frequency = 12),
             ts(runif(150), end =  c(2021,1), frequency = 12),
             ts(runif(75), end =  c(2021,1), frequency = 4),
             ts(runif(100), end =  c(2021,1), frequency = 12),
             ts(runif(25), end =  c(2021,1), frequency = 4),
             ts(runif(100), end =  c(2021,1), frequency = 12)
             )
```

Now, I'm trying to extract all quarterly time-series from this list.

Does any body have an idea how to solve this problem? Any help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of these will extract the quarterly series.  No packages are used.

```
Filter(function(x) frequency(x) == 4, list)
```

or

```
freq <- sapply(list, frequency)
list[freq == 4]
```

Also this splits the list into sublists, in the example 2 subslists, named by their frequency after which one can extract the quarterly ones like this:

```
s <- split(list, freq)  # freq defined above
s[["4"]]
```

This combines all the series having the same frequency into a single multivariate series returning a list of 2 series, one for the quarterly series and one for the monthly.

```
L <- lapply(s, do.call, what = cbind)  # s is defined above
L[["4"]]  # returns a multivariate series with all the quarterlies
```